# Looking to redirect a link

Tags: wp-redirect

Looking to redirect a certain item on a page to a subdomain. The code I want to replace is simply changing the HREF link. I can't seem to find the code though.

```
<div data-id="4" class="item item4 item-first item-last image-present">
                <a href="https://hillcountrylocal.com/cat/restaurants/">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a plugin to redirect all URLs to any other URL.
https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/